# How to add a select inside DropDownButton?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

So I've a `DropDownButton` what I need to do is add a `ComboBox` that have for each item a `checkbox` associated. Something like this:

[image]

this is actually my code for get the combobox style like this:

```
<ComboBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <CheckBox>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </CheckBox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
    <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>item 3</sys:String>
    <sys:String>item 4</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

and this is the `DropDownButton` structure:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton Name="DownButton1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DownButton, Mode=TwoWay, Path=ItemsSource}" Orientation="Vertical">
```

Note that I'm using Mahapp

Comment: Are you sure this is the UI you need? Believe it or not, I've seen this type of control used before and it confused the hell out of users (and a number of developers that then needed to maintain it!).
Why not just use checkbox controls outside of the dropdown?

Comment: @ibebbs I need a list with a checkbox, I though to implement this, your maybe have another idea?

Comment: You mean a [checked list box](http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/)?

Comment: @ibebbs have you already tried this?